# Constantly occurring dialogue box asking for authentication

Tags: updates

A dialogue box constantly pops up requesting authentication to run /usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked.  Whether I cancel or authenticate, the box disappears, nothing happens and then it will pop up again later.  I have tried setting Automatically check for updates (in Software and Updates) to "Never" but that makes no difference.  Using Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely Gnome rather than core Ubuntu, but you can disable the notification completely with this:

```
gsettings set com.ubuntu.update-notifier no-show-notifications true
```

This will not affect your ability to update/upgrade when you choose to do so.